# Websphere AS 7.0 login

Tags: websphere

All,
I am using Websphere AS 7.0 along with my RAD 7.5.
When I try to use the Admin console from with in RAD (http://localhost:9061/ibm/console)

and from a different browser (IE/Firefox), I get the following two options:

Option 1: Log out the other user with the same user ID. You can recover changes made during the other user's session.
Option 2:  Return to the Login page and enter a different user ID

[image: See image] [image: My IBM console screen]

I wanted to know if there is any setting in WAS7 that I can tweak so that I can access the console from with in RAD and different browser (on local system as well as remote)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebSphere console doesn't allow you to login with same user more than once, you will have to log out on other machine before you can log in.

Alternatively, as Darioo suggested, create a new user with required rights/role

Regards
Babajide (aka Prince)

Answer (score 1):

Not from my knowledge, but you can always create another admin user and use one just for RAD and other for console from a browser.

Comment: can you point me to a page/reference to do that please? As I mentioned I am new to WAS.

Answer (score 0):

The message you have is not a browser issue. You probably didn't hit log out or saved your changes when you last logged in. If you are developing locally on your machine or are sure you are not interferring with anybody's work then I guess you can simply choose the first option. Otherwise I would follow Darioo's advice if you need to get several users logged in at the same time.

Now for the browser, I assume you are accessing the console from by right-clicking the server in the Servers view and choosing Run administrative console. In Preferences->Web Browser you get 2 options: use  the internal browser or use an external browser. With the second option you can add/remove/configure browsers from there.

Also you can use Run->External tool if for any reason the above is not sufficient.